# How do I renew a namecoin domain?

Tags: blockchain, namecoin

I own a couple domains, I would just like to renew them using the CLI. I see a thing to renew using the QT client, but my domains are in my CLI wallet, not my QT client wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to https://forum.namecoin.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=1057&sid=ecc0431681aea878e1add77c55dcd741

First of all make sure your CLI client is synchronized, i.e. getinfo (or better: getblockcount) gives you the same block number as you get at http://namecoin.webbtc.com/ or http://explorer.namecoin.info/stats/block_count.txt
You should also check if the amount of NMCs in your wallet is sufficient for the renewal command(s). One renew or update attempt costs you 0.005 NMC or less.

Renewing a name is identical to updating a name. In both cases you use name_update, and the command line looks like this:

```
./namecoin-cli name_update name "value"
```

Example: if you own the name d/hrdwdmrbl (which translates to the domain name hrdwdmrbl.bit) then your name renewal command could be:

```
./namecoin-cli name_update d/hrdwdmrbl "{\"map\":{\"\":\"93.184.216.34\"}}"
```

Notes:
- The example above is correct for Linux or Mac OSX. I think it looks slightly different in MS-Windows. It may need double or triple backslashes for escaping the inner doublequotes (e.g. "{\\"map\\" ... )
- Older Namecoin client versions use ./namecoind instead of ./namecoin-cli
- If you get it wrong then you either get an error message and you can try again instantly, or you don't get an error message and you have to wait for at least 1 confirmation before you can update again. You can always check the results of your commands with listtransactions